# diff two big files in Python

Tags: python, diff

I have two big text files, near 2GB each. I need something like `diff f1.txt f2.txt` . Is there any way to do this task fast in python? Standard `difflib` is too slow. I assume there is faster way, because `difflib` is fully implemented in Python.

Comment: Why not use `diff f1.txt f2.txt`?

Comment: @delnan: because it will make my script platform dependent. Get diff of files is only one of other parts of script

Comment: Is it feasible to try it with psyco acceleration or an Unladen Swallow or PyPy build?

Comment: For a little reference, can you tell us how long difflib is taking to compare the files on your computer and what kind of speedup you would like to see?

Comment: @ncoghlan no, this script is part of very large software complex. I have only pure python-2.4, also I am not able to use any GPL libraries (BSD only).

Comment: @marr75 standard diff utility took near one-two minutes, depends of files(1-2GB). I was waiting for 7minutes with python difflib script with 150MB file and after had cancelled it without any result obtained.

Comment: What's the end goal? Are you just trying to tell whether they differ, or to get specific information about how much they differ? Perhaps there's another method depending on what output you end up needing.

Comment: @chmullig I need to get two lists(or files). First list must contain strings that were added in second file, and second list must contain strings that were removed in second file.

Answer (score 6):

How about using difflib in way that you script can handle big files? Don't load the files in memory, but iterate through the files of the files and diff in chunks. For e.g 100 lines at a time.

```
import difflib

d = difflib.Differ()

f1 = open('bigfile1')
f2 = open('bigfile2')

b1 = []
b2 = []

for n, lines in enumerate(zip(f1,f2)):
    if not (n % 100 == 0):
        b1.append(lines[0])
        b2.append(lines[1])
    else:
        diff = d.compare("".join(b1), "".join(b2))
        b1 = []
        b2 = []
        print ''.join(list(diff))

diff = d.compare("".join(b1), "".join(b2))
print ''.join(list(diff))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Your other fast and portable option would be ask the users to install diff utility for the platform and then use that via python wrapper.

Comment: Python's `difflib` is just slow no matter what you do. Two almost identical files of 1MB each, take me 0.5sec at best case and a few minutes at worst case. Binary diff takes 0.033s.