# Python difflib with long diff blocks

Tags: python, diff

I was using Python's `difflib` to create comprehensive differential logs between rather long files. Everything was running smoothly, until I encountered problem of never-ending diffs. After digging around, it turned out that `difflib` cannot handle long sequences of semi-matching lines. 
Here is a (somewhat minimal) example:

```
import sys
import random
import difflib

def make_file(fname, dlines):
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write("This is a small file with a long sequence of different lines\n")
        f.write("Some of the starting lines could differ {}\n".format(random.random()))
        f.write("...\n")
        f.write("...\n")
        f.write("...\n")
        f.write("...\n")
        for i in range(dlines):
            f.write("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(i, i+random.random()/100, i+random.random()/10000, i+random.random()/1000000))

make_file("a.txt", 125)
make_file("b.txt", 125)

with open("a.txt") as ff:
    fromlines = ff.readlines()
with open("b.txt") as tf:
    tolines = tf.readlines()

diff = difflib.ndiff(fromlines, tolines)

sys.stdout.writelines(diff)
```

Even for the 125 lines in the example, it took Python over 4 seconds to compute and print the diff, while for GNU Diff it took literally a few milliseconds. And I'm facing problems, where the number of lines is approx. 100 times larger.

Is there a sensible solution to the issue? I hoped for using `difflib`, as it produces rather nice HTML diffs, but I am open to suggestions. I need a portable solution, that would work on as many platforms as possible, although I am already considering porting GNU Diff for the matter :). Hacking into `difflib` is also possible as long as I wouldn't have to literally rewrite the whole library.

PS. The files might have variable-length prefixes, so splitting them into parts without aligning diff context might not be the best idea.

Comment: It seems it is just slow. See for instance: http://bugs.python.org/issue11740 (especially http://bugs.python.org/issue11740#msg132794 -- Differ._fancy_replace might be the thing to blame) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899146/diff-two-big-files-in-python The suggested solution was to use diff or windiff via python wrapper.